# Jquery tooltip not hiding when drag and drop the tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tooltip

I am using an Angular directive where I am having the anchor tag like below.

```
<a xt-tooltip title="{{readToolTip(item)}}" ng-class="isSelected(item)">
```

and I am having another directive for "xtTooltip" as

```
module.directive("xtTooltip",[tooltip]);
    function tooltip() {

        return {
            priority: 0,
            restrict: "A",
            scope: false,
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope,root,attrs,controller) {
            $(root).tooltip({
                position: {
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left+20 bottom",
                    collison: "none fit"
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

When I drag and drop the anchor tag , the tooltip is visible until I hover the mouse over the anchor tag. How can hide this while I drag and drop the item?